# What does this error message mean in appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search, jinja2, python-2.x, webapp2

```
Search failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~montaoproject/2013e.368508855356793432/search_demo.py", line 87, in find_documents
    return index.search(query)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/search/search.py", line 2732, in search
    _CheckStatus(response.status())
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/search/search.py", line 413, in _CheckStatus
    raise _ERROR_MAP[status.code()](status.error_detail())
InvalidRequest: Failed to execute search request ""
```

Code

```
def find_documents(query_string, limit, cursor):
    try:
        date_desc = search.SortExpression(expression='date',
                direction=search.SortExpression.DESCENDING,
                default_value=datetime.now().date())

        hr_desc = search.SortExpression(expression='hour',
                direction=search.SortExpression.DESCENDING,
                default_value=datetime.now().hour)

        min_desc = search.SortExpression(expression='minute',
                direction=search.SortExpression.DESCENDING,
                default_value=datetime.now().minute)

        # Sort up to 5000 matching results by subject in descending order

        sort = search.SortOptions(expressions=[date_desc, hr_desc,
                                  min_desc], limit=10000)

        # Set query options

        options = search.QueryOptions(limit=limit, cursor=cursor,
                sort_options=sort, number_found_accuracy=10000)  # the number of results to return

            # returned_fields=['author', 'subject', 'summary'],
            # snippeted_fields=['content']

        query = search.Query(query_string=query_string, options=options)
        index = search.Index(name=_INDEX_NAME)

        # Execute the query

        return index.search(query)
    except search.Error:
        logging.exception('Search failed')
    return None

class USA(SearchBaseHandler):

    def get(self):
        """Handles a get request with a query."""

        regionname = 'New York'
        region = Region.all().filter('name = ', regionname).get()

        cursor = self.request.get('cursor')

        uri = urlparse(self.request.uri)
        query = ''
        if uri.query:
            query = parse_qs(uri.query)
            try:
                query = query['query'][0]
            except KeyError, err:
                query = ''

                # logging.info('KeyError')

        # logging.info('search cursor: %s', search.Cursor())

        if cursor:
            results = find_documents(query, 50, search.Cursor(cursor))
        else:
            results = find_documents(query, 50, search.Cursor())

        next_cursor = None

        if results and results.cursor:
            next_cursor = results.cursor.web_safe_string

        query = query.replace(' and company_ad=0', ''
                              ).replace(' and company_ad=1', '')

        # logging.info('next cursor: %s', str(next_cursor))

        template_values = {
            'results': results,
            'cursor': next_cursor,
            'number_returned': len(results.results),
            'user': users.get_current_user(),
            'loggedin': self.logged_in,
            'region': region,
            'regionname': regionname,
            'city': '',
            'cityentity': None,
            'request': self.request,
            'form': SearchForm(),
            'query': query,
            }
        self.render_template('q.htm', template_values)
```

### Update

A page 2 link that worked looks like this

`q?query=regionID%3D4702187&cursor=False:CqoECuYBCtgB_wDAQM7xgAD_AP8A_wD__wDAQCQA_wD_AP8A_wD_AP__AMBAPwD_AP8A_wD_AP8A___-9wlMHAj_jv9jjIGSkJGLnpCPjZCVmpyL_wB0baCgmYuMoKD_AF2ej4-akZiWkZr_AHN0bZaRm5qH_wBdnpuM_wBzdG2bkJyglpv_AF2emMaFmZLOiZ2RrZedzL2Gnc2Pk6bMrYa8iIysvpS5lLi1vMaRiLKy_wBzf56YxoWZks6JnZGtl53MvYadzY-TpsythryIjKy-lLmUuLW8xpGIsrL_AP_-EDIh4o_3av1KJSkSDURvY3VtZW50SW5kZXganwEoQU5EIChJUyAiY3VzdG9tZXJfbmFtZSIgImFwcGVuZ2luZSIpIChJUyAiZ3JvdXBfbmFtZSIgInN-bW9udGFvcHJvamVjdCIpIChJUyAibmFtZXNwYWNlIiAiIikgKElTICJpbmRleF9uYW1lIiAiYWRzIikgKEVRIDQ3MDIxODcuMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAgInNuYnJfcmVnaW9uSUQiKSk6GwoOKE4gc2RhdGVfZGF0ZSkQARkAAEANwvpzQjoaCg0oTiBzbmJyX2hvdXIpEAEZAAAAAAAAKEA6HAoPKE4gc25icl9taW51dGUpEAEZAAAAAACASUBKHAgBOhVzdDpidGlfZ2VuZXJpY19zY29yZXJAkE5SGQoMKE4gb3JkZXJfaWQpEAEZAAAAAAAA8P8`

I'll try to see if I can make it fail randomly, then we'll know it's a timeout error. And if it's a timeout error then I can cache it with memcache and do some less expensive calls to avoid roundtrips and it will work(?)

I'm doing this both for blank queries and for reiog-based search where I limit the search to a region like above and the regionID is a field of the indexed document. You may check the [live site][1] to have a look at the action.

### Update 2

A page 2 link that worked looks like this

`/q?query=&cursor=False:CocECuYBCtgB_wDAQM8JAP8A_wD_AP8A__8AwEAkAP8A_wD_AP8A_wD__wDAQECAAP8A_wD_AP8A___-9wltwdL_Iv_jjIGSkJGLnpCPjZCVmpyL_wB0baCgmYuMoKD_AF2ej4-akZiWkZr_AHN0bZaRm5qH_wBdnpuM_wBzdG2bkJyglpv_AF2emMaFmZLOiZ2RrZedzL2Gnc2Pk6bMrYa8iIysvpS5lLi2vJXLrrKy_wBzf56YxoWZks6JnZGtl53MvYadzY-TpsythryIjKy-lLmUuLa8lcuusrL_AP_-EDIh4o_3av1KJSkSDURvY3VtZW50SW5kZXgafShBTkQgKElTICJjdXN0b21lcl9uYW1lIiAiYXBwZW5naW5lIikgKElTICJncm91cF9uYW1lIiAic35tb250YW9wcm9qZWN0IikgKElTICJuYW1lc3BhY2UiICIiKSAoSVMgImluZGV4X25hbWUiICJhZHMiKSAoVFJVRSkpOhsKDihOIHNkYXRlX2RhdGUpEAEZAABADcL6c0I6GgoNKE4gc25icl9ob3VyKRABGQAAAAAAACxAOhwKDyhOIHNuYnJfbWludXRlKRABGQAAAAAAgElAShwIAToVc3Q6YnRpX2dlbmVyaWNfc2NvcmVyQJBOUhkKDChOIG9yZGVyX2lkKRABGQAAAAAAAPD_`

If I press reload it can work or fail, so it looks like a random error. Any ideas?

Comment: the "False:" before the cursor string, is that part of search cursor?

Comment: Does the search query change between first call and second call?

Comment: @Bert yes, the "False:" is part of the cursor. I don't know why. And the query does not change between the two calls. The second call fails from a straight reloa which is odd.

Comment: @Bert You solved it. Put your comment in an answer and you'll get the bounty. I already stated the answer.

Comment: @Programmer400 - Can you share how this was solved?

Comment: @minocha As soon as I know what is was. It was indeed solved and I think it was some trivial mistake.

Comment: @Programmer400 - apart from empty queries not working with faceted+sort_options, I'm looking for other problems. Please do share if you find out :) thanks

Comment: `False` in the beginning of the cursor means that there will be per page generated cursors see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/cursorclass#Constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `Failed to execute search request ""` it looks like your query is empty. That could be the problem.

Comment: If it happens randomly (not always on the same page), it could be caused by timeouts. According to [GAE Issue #8370](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8370#c15), the latency of the query should not be > 5 seconds. You might try to remove the sorting to see if it helps. If you narrow it down to sorting, you may try to combine all your date and time values into one field. If it still doesn't help, you may try presorting the documents. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855711/full-text-search-api-for-app-engine-java/15607878#15607878).