# TransientError: Temporary search service error - Python Google App Engine Search

Tags: google-app-engine, google-search-api, gae-search

I'm trying to run a query and sorting by 'updated_at' field using a large number_found_accuracy:

```
order_options = search.SortOptions(
    expressions=[search.SortExpression(expression='updated_at',
                                   direction=search.SortExpression.DESCENDING)])

query_options = search.QueryOptions(
    limit=50,
    cursor=search.Cursor(),
    sort_options=order_options,
    number_found_accuracy=25000)

index = search.Index('contacts', namespace='default')
query_future = index.search_async(search.Query("", options=query_options))
contacts = query_future.get_result()
```

When get_result() is called i get the error bellow:

> File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/3b44e98ed7fbb86b/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in **call**
>   rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
>   File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/3b44e98ed7fbb86b/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in **call**
>   rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
>   File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/3b44e98ed7fbb86b/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
>   return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
>   File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/3b44e98ed7fbb86b/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in **call**
>   return handler.dispatch()
>   File "/base/data/home/apps/p~imobzi-app/20181127t101400.414282042583891084/modules/base_handler.py", line 72, in dispatch
>   super(BaseHandler, self).dispatch()
>   File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/3b44e98ed7fbb86b/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
>   return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
>   File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/3b44e98ed7fbb86b/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
>   return method(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/base/data/home/apps/p~imobzi-app/20181127t101400.414282042583891084/main.py", line 132, in get
>   contacts = query_future.get_result()
>   File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/3b44e98ed7fbb86b/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/search/search.py", line 281, in get_result
>   raise _ToSearchError(e)
>   TransientError: Temporary search service error

The error occurs when i use "number_found_accuracy" and "sort_options" in same query when query result is large (this query return more than 50,000 results).

If "number_found_accuracy" or "sort_options" is removed from query_options i get the result normally, but if both is in query_options, the error occurs.

In a normal case i'd remove "number_found_accuracy" from query, but i need to show the result count for the user and sort it by updated_at field. Does anyone know a way to solve this? This occurs only when a deploy project to server, in a local/development environment, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason for this error can be that the length of the query exceeds the limit of 2000 characters as specified in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/query_strings).

There is also a limitation on sorting that can be worked around by presorting your documents in the index using Document rank as explained in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15607878/10553701).

Also note that as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/searchresultsclass#SearchResults_number_found)

> **number_found:**
>   Returns an approximate number of documents matching the query. QueryOptions defining post-processing of the search results. If the QueryOptions.number_found_accuracy parameter were set to 100, then number_found <= 100 is accurate.

Since you have set `number_found_accuracy=25000`, any search result with a size greater than 25000 will be an approximate.